# pipeline assets precompile disable does not seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have disabled pipeline assets precompile. For that I have the following line in my **config/application.rb & config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

I am trying to deploy in development environment with Capistrano3. When I run deploy command I find assets are precompiled.

$cap development deploy --trace

```
DEBUG [8b4a938e] Command: cd /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/a/releases/20140122054901 && ( RAILS_ENV=development ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.0.0-p353 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [8b4a938e]    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/ano_dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=development RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEBUG [8b4a938e]    
INFO [8b4a938e] Finished in 8.812 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

What else I need to do to avoid assets  pre compilation. It further gives

Comment: in `Capfile` this line commented `load 'deploy/assets'`?

Comment: @Monk_Code- I am using capistrano 3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What's in your Capfile?

If you have

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
```

then it will precompile your assets because capistrano/rails also includes bundler, rails/assets and rails/migrations.

https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/rails.rb
https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake

If you still want bundler and migrations but not assets, you can include them individually in your Capfile, just make sure you don't still require 'capistrano/rails':

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

Comment: for my condition, some how i didnt see export RAILS_ENV=staging for my staging deployment. instead of this, i use capistrano/rails and setting set :assets_roles, [] works

Answer (score 15):

For my case, our team uses a shared gem for all of our Rails apps, and the shared gem requires 'capistrano/rails' (thus bringing in the assets compilation). For the app that did not handle this, all we did was add:

```
set :assets_roles, []
```

in `config/deploy.rb` and this makes capistrano-rails skip asset precompilation.